# My tablet's orientation is 180 degrees (upside is down)?

Tags: android, orientation

When developing the app it looks great on my virtual devices.

But when trying it on my real tablet it displays the whole app upside down!

1. Can I change the orientation by 180 degrees somewhere in the android settings?
2. Can I change my code slightly to display the app in 180 degrees?

Please note that I am using api8  (android 2.2)

Answer (score 1):

You can set the screen orientation of the activity in the AndroidManifest.xml file
e.g

```
<activity 
.
.
android:screenOrientation="reverseLandscape"
/>
```

You can use other options see the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html)

Comment: Sounds exactly what I need but it gave me the following error:

Comment: error: Error: String types not allowed (at 'screenOrientation' with value 
 'reversePortrait').

Comment: My bad, reverseLandscape should be in quotes, updated my answer

Comment: Thanks.  It seems to be the best solution, but unfortunately It works since api9+ and I need my app to be compatible with api8.

Is there any other solution?   Is there a way to do it in api8?

Comment: For the benefit of all (taken from the official android-docs):

"reversePortrait" Portrait orientation in the opposite direction from normal portrait. Added in API level 9.

Answer (score 0):

I realize the question is about 2.2, however this valuable piece of code (2.3+) handles both orientations of landscape inside your manifest:

```
android:screenOrientation="sensorLandscape"
```